Polygon Boundary in 3D Space
A simple polygon (interior included) is a manifold with boundary being homeomorphic to a closed disk. Its (manifold) boundary is a non-intersecting closed polygonal chain. Viewed as a subset of the plane, its topological boundary is the same polygonal chain. A non-simple polygon is one whose polygonal chain contains at least one pair of intersecting
edges. It is not a manifold and therefore has no manifold boundary but its topological boundary in the plane is again its closed polygonal chain if we consider its interior to be the points that when casting a ray from the point in any direction intersects the boundary edges an odd number of times.
Embedding either polygon in 3 dimensional space has no effect on its status as a manifold but its topological boundary is no longer its polygonal chain. It is the entire polygon (simple or not) itself. I would like to understand what if any significance the polygonal chains in 3 dimension have and their relationship to the polygons. Is there a "boundary-like" term one can use to refer to these chains relative to their polygons?
